# Data transform on SQL insert

Tags: sql, excel, insert

I'm creating a SQL table from an Excel file.  The excel file is not in a transactional format though and I'm having a hard time figuring the SQL to do this correctly.

Excel file has the following column names:

```
Dept code, Dept Name, ..., 1962, 1963, 1964, ..., 2022
```

Each field in the "year" columns have a dollar value in them.

I'd like to import this in a transactional format with a record for each dept code/name and a 'year' column, and a 'value' column.

Output would look like this:

Columns:

```
Dept Code, Dept Name, Year, Value
```

Data:

```
001, Marketing, 1962, $19,000
001, Marketing, 1963, $20,000         
etc, etc...
```

Any hints on how to do this, elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String the non-year/value entries together with something like:

```
=A2&"|"&B2&"|"&C2
```

[Unpivot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20541905/convert-matrix-to-3-column-table-reverse-pivot-unpivot-flatten-normal) and split the combined column with Text to Columns and `|` as the delimiter.